# Datatables select row programmatically without triggering select event

Tags: javascript, datatables

In Datatable's Select plugin, there is a way to programmatically select a row:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().select()

But this will also trigger the row's select event, which is not ideal in my context as it will get into an infinite loop...

Is there a way of doing this without having to use some control variable?

The bit in their API for the select function is as follows :

```
apiRegisterPlural( 'rows().select()', 'row().select()', function ( select ) {
    var api = this;

    if ( select === false ) {
        return this.deselect();
    }

    this.iterator( 'row', function ( ctx, idx ) {
        clear( ctx );

        ctx.aoData[ idx ]._select_selected = true;
        $( ctx.aoData[ idx ].nTr ).addClass( ctx._select.className );
    } );

    this.iterator( 'table', function ( ctx, i ) {
        eventTrigger( api, 'select', [ 'row', api[i] ], true );
    } );

    return this;
} );
```

It seems I just need to figure out the `ctx.aoData[ idx ]._select_selected = true;` part, is ctx the row object? I'm clueless.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but for those coming here later on might like an answer.

Datatables has a select event and a user-select event.

Just use the user-select event where applicable and leave the select event for all other purposes.
https://datatables.net/reference/event/user-select

For example,

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    select: true
} );
 
table
    .on( 'user-select', function ( e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent ) {
        if ( originalEvent.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img' ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } );
```

Update : Just to add an additional choice since the user-select event does fire even on a deselect.  One way to avoid some issues I think many people have is when the table is initialized they programmatically select items.  You can avoid this trigger by simply enabling your select and deselect events only after the table has been initialized.

Datatables has an initComplete event. So do it like so.  Where table is a variable to your datatable reference.

```
initComplete: function(settings, json) { 
  table.on('select', function( e, dt, type, indexes ) {

  });
}
```